# Selenium Python3 - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Newbie to automation with Selenium/Python. I'm getting blocked automating a sign up form. The drop down is a required element but I'm getting the following error...

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tag_name'

I've posted my code below and can't find any answer online as to why this would be. Any/all help greatly appreciated.

````
from re import X
from socket import timeout
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from locale import currency
from operator import index
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from unicodedata import name
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait 
web = webdriver.Chrome("/home/nosra/chromedriver")
#class selenium :webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(web, timeout, poll_frequency=0.5, ignored_exceptions=None)


df=pd.read_excel('info1.xlsx')
url=["https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScGMoYVsxtsQ0Je4RTYEZndWrKkdt5jJwXBcMAcOia2WuIRtA/viewform?usp=sf_link"]
for link in url:  
    for i in df.index :
     web.get(link)
     entry=df.loc[i]     
     name=web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
     time.sleep(1)
     name.send_keys(entry['name'])
     time.sleep(1)
     lastName=web.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
     time.sleep(2)
     lastName.send_keys(entry['lastName '])
    
select_C=Select(web.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='mG61Hd']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/span"))
select_C.select_by_index(1)```
````

Comment: At which line are you getting the error exactly?

Answer (score -1):

`select_C` defined wrong: you should pass *single* WebElement to `Select` (so you need to use `web.find_element` instead of `web.find_elements`) and also your XPath should fetch `select` node not `span`. `Select` class is not applicable here. Just click on

```
web.find_element('xpath', '//div[@role="option"]').click()
```

to open drop-down menu and then

```
web.find_element('xpath', '//div[@data-value="Tunisia" and @aria-selected="false"]').click()
```

to select option